# JPA entity sharing among different entity managers

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

- Is it allowed according to the JPA 2.0 spec to **share an entity between two different entity managers**, e.g. in the following way:

  ```
  A entityA = em1.find(entityA.class,1L);
  B entityB = new entityB();
  b.setA(entityA); //entityB refers to entityA via @ManyToOne reference, cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST is enabled
  em2.persist(entityB);
  em2.flush();
  ```
- Does the answer change if the line `em1.detach(entityA);` will be inserted between the first and second line? (or in other words: is the **sharing of detached entities** allowed among different entity managers)

Answer (score 0):

- No, it's not allowed to have a single entity *managed* by multiple `EntityManager`s
- Yes, if you have a *detached* entity it's allowed to make it *managed* by another `EntityManager`, for example, using `merge()`

However, in your case `EntityManager` should throw an exception, because it's not allowed to apply `persist()` (in your case, by cascading) to detached entities. You should either remove cascading option or use `merge()` instead of `persist()`.

And if you remove cascading I think it would be possible to run this code even without `detach()`, because in that case `entityA` doesn't become managed by `em2`.